# How can I use a global temporary table with Hibernate session?

Tags: hibernate, session, oracle11g, database-connection

I created a global temporary table in my database.  I'm using it to merge a small amount of processed data into a much larger table.

I'm writing to the temporary table and deleting from it within a service that responds to requests one at a time.  Each request should be using a different database session, so that the data doesn't collide between requests. That is, I want the database session to close and reopen between requests so that the data for one request is not visible to the data from the next request.

Our application uses Hibernate to manage database sessions.  I'm finding it hard to understand from the documentation the relationship between a database session and a hibernate session -- but it appears that Hibernate is giving me the same database session in my class even if I call openSession() and then session.close() between requests.  I wrote some test code to test this behaviour out.

```
public void testTemporaryTable() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    writeToTemporary(session);
    System.out.println(countDataInTemporary(session));
    ...
    mergeFromTemporay(session);
    // Here I'm hoping for a closed db session, to make the data disappear:
    session.close();

}
```

When I run this twice from the same main thread, the first time I see 70,000 results in the temporary table.  The second time I run it, I see 140,000 results.  If the database session had actually closed and the session factory openSession gave me a new database session, I should only see 70,000 results the second time.

I'm hoping there's an easy solution to this because the temporary table makes it much easier to manage the large quantities of data that get processed.

---

What I've discovered:

- A Hibernate session is not a one to one correspondence with a database session.  In our system we are using a connection pool, and the Hibernate session uses a connection from the pool. The benefit of using a connection pool and hibernate sessions is to reduce the need for creating connections, which is expensive.

The solution:

- Truncate the temporary table between uses within the same service thread.

Why a temporary table?

- The data is deleted when the service is shut down, which happens in between user sessions.
- The data is deleted if the service is aborted partway through processing.  Which unfortunately happens frequently enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hibernate session is not a one to one correspondence with a database session.  So, to use a temporary table with no guarantee that the database session will be renewed between subsequent hibernate sessions, it should be truncated to remove the data.  This is a low cost operation.